# PyDev: Insert spaces for tabs not working

Tags: pydev

Why  is `Window > Prefences > PyDev > Editor > Tabs > "Replace tabs with spaces when typing?" = Yes` not working

I have also set `.. > General > Text Editors > "Insert spaces for tabs" = Yes` but I'm still getting tabs and not spaces which results in a code freak-up.

Comment: Did you try to reopen the editor after changing the settings? Maybe the setting is not updated to the existing editors?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa This is exactly why I love but also **hate** Eclipse.. Yes, restarting Eclipse made it work. Thank you. Do you want to provide an answer for those people who might run into the same issue? ^^

Comment: No problem - glad my nose was right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart Eclipse.

Eclipse settings changes might not be updated on already open editor tabs.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Restart Eclipse before making any further steps (e.g. raging out etc.)

Comment: I also had to close the .py-file tab and reopen it (After restarting Eclipse)

Comment: Using Eclipse  2022-09 with PyDev 10.0.02022 I also had to

1: change both settings described in answer
2: close all editors
3: restart Eclipse
4: reopen python editors again

Comment: Surprised to find out anyone tries to use Eclipse for Python in 2022, as there are so many better IDEs and editors available.